# Why does this rails regex not work?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
[28] pry(main)> a
=> "\\r\\np"
[30] pry(main)> a.gsub('\\\\','\\')
=> "\\r\\np"
```

It should have returned :

```
"\r\np"
```

.. or at least I wanted it to return that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `a` doesn't contain two backslashes at any point. `a` consists of these five characters:

- `\`
- `r`
- `\`
- `n`
- `p`

When you ask pry to inspect it, it has to show the escaping `\` characters for each literal `\`; if you run `puts a` you should see `\r\np`

If you want to edit the string to contain the control codes for Carriage Return and Newline, you probably want:

```
a.gsub('\\r', "\r").gsub('\\n', "\n")
```